# How add uniqe element from List to ObservableCollection by Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a question about check for if object in one List exists in another and if not add them into second list all by Linq. Actually I have two loops with one condition:

```
 foreach (var p in seznamVlaku.Select(s => s.ProjizdejiciStanicemi)) {
            foreach (var l in p) {
                if(_nodes.Any(a => a.ID != l.Key.ID)){
                    _nodes.Add(new Node() {Name = l.Key.Jmeno, ID = l.Key.ID, X = l.Key.X, Y = l.Key.Y });
                }
            }
        }
```

It is possible do this faster by Linq query?

Comment: This `_nodes.Any(a => a.ID != l.Key.ID)` means 'if there is node that has different id then `_nodes.Add(...)`'. Is it a typo ? Shouldn't it be: `!_nodes.Any(a => a.ID == l.Key.ID)` ?

Comment: You can use [`IEnumerable.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter out elements that exist in a different list. `NewList.AddRange(OriginalList.Except(TheOtherList));`

Comment: @BradleyUffner that would require a custom equality comparer, or MoreLinq's `ExceptBy`.

Comment: Fabian you have right :)

Comment: Is `_nodes` a `List<T>` collection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a much **faster** way, you have to check if `l` already exists in `_nodes`, and that for each `l`. If you could optimize that on a higher level I can't tell without knowing what this is doing.

If you simply want a shorter LINQ statement, you can use `SelectMany`:

```
foreach(var l in sznamVlaku.SelectMany(s => s.ProjizdejiciStanicemi)
                           .Where(x => _nodes.All(a => a.ID != x.Key.ID)))
    _nodes.Add(new Node() {Name = l.Key.Jmeno, ID = l.Key.ID, X = l.Key.X, Y = l.Key.Y });
```

Note that I used `All` instead of `Any`, because you want to find all `l` where **all** nodes have a different `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need two foreach. Instead use SelectMany.

Your example:

```
foreach (var p in seznamVlaku.Select(s => s.ProjizdejiciStanicemi))
{
    foreach (var l in p)
    {
    }
}
```

We can write like and it'd be the same:

```
foreach (var node in seznamVlaku.SelectMany(list => list.ProjizdejiciStanicemi))
{
}
```

2. You can add condition (existing item) add to pipeline of linq query

Code:

```
foreach (var node in seznamVlaku
    .SelectMany(list => list.ProjizdejiciStanicemi)
    .Where(item => nodes
        .Exists(node => node.ID != item.ID)))
{
    _nodes.Add(new Node() {Name = node.Key.Jmeno, ID = node.Key.ID, X = node.Key.X, Y = node.Key.Y });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be considerably faster because it uses hashing instead of nested loops:

```
// build a HashSet of your key's type (I'm assuming integers here) containing all your current elements' keys in the _nodes ObservableCollection
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(_nodes.Select(n => n.ID));

foreach (var l in seznamVlaku.SelectMany(s => s.ProjizdejiciStanicemi)) {
    // if you can add the element's ID to the HashSet it hasn't been added before
    if(hashSet.Add(l.Key.ID)) {
        _nodes.Add(new Node() {Name = l.Key.Jmeno, ID = l.Key.ID, X = l.Key.X, Y = l.Key.Y });
    }
}
```